# Django REST Swagger: List and Retrieve functions are not detected by Swagger

Tags: python, django, rest, django-rest-framework, django-swagger

I'm using django-rest-swagger version: 2.0.5 and django-rest-framework version: 3.4.6.

I realiased that when I use `list` or `retrieve` functions the Swagger can not detect them as new endpoints.

I have the following code in my views.py file:

```
from rest_framework.viewsets import ViewSet

class OrdersViewSet(ViewSet):
    lookup_field = 'uuid'

    def list(self, request: Request, *args, **kwargs):
        try:
            changeset = OrderSyncHelper().get_order_list_data()
            return Response(status=HTTP_200_OK, data=changeset)
        except (KeyError, ValueError) as e:
            return Response(status=HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST, data=e.args)

    def retrieve(self, request: Request, uuid: str, *args, **kwargs):
        try:
            changeset = OrderSyncHelper().get_order_data(uuid)
            return Response(status=HTTP_200_OK, data=changeset)
        except (KeyError, ValueError) as e:
            return Response(status=HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST, data=e.args)
```

I was expecting to see in the openapi.json file the following endpoints:

- orders/
- orders/{uuid}/

But they are not presented. Should I add something specific to these functions in order to be detected by Swagger?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue fixed when I tried to upgrade the django-rest-swagger to `version 2.1.1`.

So in version 2.1.1 the Swagger is able to detect endpoints which are implemented using `retrieve` or `list` functions